Lagrange interpolation error function derivation
##Deriving the Error Function of Lagrange Interpolation
I am studying Lagrange interpolation and have come across the error function given by:
$$
E_n(x) = f(x) - P_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!} \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - x_i)
$$
where $f(x)$ is the original function, $ P_n(x)$ is the polynomial interpolation, and $\zeta$ is some point in the interval of interpolation.
I have the expression for the error function, but I am having trouble understanding how it is derived.
Can someone explain the derivation of $E_n(x)$ and the significance of $\zeta$ in this formula?
